# What is the preferred method of using feature flags in Flask?

Tags: docker, nginx, feature-flags, feature-toggles, flask

I wanted to ask what the preferred tool, method or framework is when using feature flags with Flask applications. The main problem is that the most [relevant result](https://github.com/trustrachel/Flask-FeatureFlags) has not seen an update since 3 years, there is only one non-free [feature flag as a service](https://launchdarkly.com/), and the alternative to roll it myself with Environment variables or something with injecting values in the request header without Nginx. For context, it is a relatively [small application](https://github.com/mayaculpa/veleda) that is [containerized](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) and has an [automatic Nginx reverse proxy](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion).

Therefore, the question is what is the defacto method for implementing feature flags in Flask apps?

Comment: I've no idea about what flask is, but if there's no maintained method, this is usually the sign rolling your own according to your constraints is the way to go (or the community around is very small and no one can/want to share their code)